# Object does not show in render (Cycles) (Blender 2.82)

Tags: rendering

I'm at my wits end. I am trying to render my scene and everything shows up except for the body of my character. I did duplicate part of its mesh to create a molded piece of clothing and then proceeded to separate it from the original mesh, but from then on, my character stopped showing up in my renders. It does show up in render mode though. I read online that it might be fixed using the duplicate tab in the object properties, something to do with duplicating part of an object, but there is no such option in 2.82.

Please help me I'm going crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I hope I can save someone's time and fix their problem if they ever come across the same issue.

Select the object that doesn't render, go into object properties, scroll down to Instancing, select None and then Render Instancer.

I don't know why it changed the setting by itself, I never clicked on this nor did this ever happen to me before after duplicating part of an object. Whatever